# Installing Hugo web engine without SSH

Tags: ssh, go, hugo

I use a basic hosting service that does not include secure shell access, Is there another way that I can deploy Hugo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After running `hugo server` for local web development, you need to do
>   a final hugo run without the `server` command and without `--watch` or
>   `-w` to rebuild your site.
>
> then, You may deploy your site by copying the `public/` directory (by
>   FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, Rsync, git push, etc.) to your web host.

Since Hugo generates a static website, your site can be hosted anywhere as in the most basic host provide FTP access. For more please see [Using Hugo](https://gohugo.io/overview/usage/)